# How can I print another version of the board without actually changing it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose the

```
board = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

and I want to have a function that print the board in a readable version which would be like

```
new_board = [['X', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'O', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

This method does not change the actual board. It prints `'X'` for `1`, `'O'` for `2`, and empty space (`' '`) for `0`.

Comment: Hint: `" XO"[n]`, where `n` is one of the numbers in your actual board, gives the corresponding character for your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a translation dictionary and a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> symbols = {1: 'X', 2: 'O', 0: ' '}
>>> [[symbols[i] for i in row] for row in board]
[['X', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'O', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

Note that you can also use a string instead of a dictionary as @jasonharper mentioned but it will only work for this case, where keys start with `0` and are sequential:

```
>>> symbols = ' XO'
```

Comment: smart mapping fits this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Or with `map` and `__getitem__`:

```
>>> symbols = ' XO'
>>> [list(map(symbols.__getitem__, x)) for x in board]
[['X', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'O', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
>>>
```

Or a nested `map`:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: list(map(symbols.__getitem__, x)), board))
[['X', ' ', ' '], [' ', 'O', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
>>>
```

This would work for a dictionary as well:

```
symbols = {1: 'X', 2: 'O', 0: ' '}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I made for you.

Put the board and the key in the function and It will print it for you:

```py
board = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
key={0:" ",1:"X",2:"O"}
def printBoard(board,key,sep="|"):
  for x in board:
    for y in x:
      print(sep,key[y],end="")
    print(sep)
printBoard(board,key)
```

The key holds the character for each value and the sep value defines what the cells are divided by.
This prints:

```
| X|  |  |
|  | O|  |
|  |  |  |
```